# Make a link load image instead of a whole new page?

Tags: html

I want to have an image portion on my webpage on the left side and on the right side I want to have small images. When I click those small images I want it to load a different image on the left side without reloading a whole webpage.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could use AJAX or iframes.

Comment: Or you could just `document.getElementById('myImageId').src = 'someOtherImage.png';`... but can we have a bit more information about what you're trying to achieve? Whatever you do, for the love of all programming gods, don't use iframes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe name="left" src="images/otherImage1.png"></iframe>
<iframe name="right" src="thumbslist.html"></iframe>
```

in thumbslist.html

```
<ul>
<li><a href="images/otherImage1.png" target="left"><img src="images/thumbs/otherImage1.png" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/otherImage2.png" target="left"><img src="images/thumbs/otherImage2.png" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/otherImage3.png" target="left"><img src="images/thumbs/otherImage3.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

of course some css is required to make the two iframes to be set adjacent to each other.